# Wordpress Cropping in Edit Image is Not Working

Tags: wordpress

I have an image that I uploaded via the WordPress media library...

[image]

I went into the media library, selected the image, and hit the EDIT IMAGE link. This brings up tools to CROP the image. So, I cropped the image, making it a horizontal image... see below:

[image]

I then clicked SAVE, and then clicked UPDATE, and returned to the post. I used my template to call the a 'large' version of the image into my page ... but the cropping was gone!

```
$reci_img_id = get_field('recipe_img'); // This calls the image from the ACF plugin
$size = 'large';
$imagesrc = $reci_img_id['sizes'][ $size ];

<img src="<?php echo $imagesrc; ?>" class="reci-img" alt="<?php echo $reci_img_id['alt'] ?>" />
```

The image shows up, but at the original dimension ratio (uncropped) ...

Can someone tell me how to get the image to show up correctly? Should I be calling the image in some other way? I don't want to crop the image using CSS, because my editors wont understand why the image is cropping "differently" than the image looks in the administration. The media image sizes in my template are thumbnail, medium and large (and full).  Any ideas how to get this to work?

Please help! Thanks!!!

Comment: Do you get a result when you try `print_r($post->recipe_img)` right before get_field? if that returns an id you can just call the standard wordpress image fetching with wp_get_attachment_image : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image

Comment: Nope. I get an error when that is run... Fatal error: Call to undefined method WP_Post::print_r() in /home/public_html/wp-content/themes/themename/single-spec.php on line 16

Comment: Right then that's not running in the loop. ACF plugin probably didn't factor that in when returning get_field. You may have to crop it elsewhere, upload the cropped file and not rely on the internal system. Way to go third party plugins!

Comment: But look into this, assuming ACF is advanced custom fields. In that case, that's actually a really good plugin. https://wordpress.org/plugins/acf-image-crop-add-on/

Comment: ACF is great. I use it for all my custom fields. I checked out the plugin ... and it works. Not ideal, but it does solve the issues I was having.

Comment: Still curious why the standard wordpress cropping wasn't working though. Would like to know how to get that to work (in case I stop using ACF)

Comment: You'd have to trace down the get_field function. If I had to guess it is just fetching "large" dimensions standardly applied to any media and not whatever "large" resolves to after it is cropped. In other words, the system may be preserving the original dimensions because you can still revert after cropping. Just a theory. You'd probably have to write an extension to patch that, or contact ACF and see if they have an answer.

Answer (score 1):

- If you crop the image in the admin interface,
- and if your template    calls for an intermediary image size like
  'large',
- and if that intermediary is not found, probably because the original didn't have enough pixels to make a 'large',
- then WordPress will fallback to the uncropped original image.

I suspect this is a bug and I haven't found a solution.

A work-around is to pull the 'full' size. Don't worry about it being too large; with modern browsers and srset the correct resolution image will be delivered to the viewer's browser.